# Polluted pipeline troubleshooting

Tags: powershell, pipeline

I have a script, in which this code fails, with an exit code of -2145124322

```
$new.ExitCode > $null
$filePath = "wusa.exe"
$argumentList = "`"\\PX_SERVER\Rollouts\Microsoft\VirtualPC\Windows6.1-KB958559-x64-RefreshPkg.msu`" /quiet /norestart"
$exitCode = (Start-Process -FilePath:$filePath -argumentList:$argumentList -wait -errorAction:Stop -PassThru).ExitCode
Write-Host $exitCode
```

Now, the main script has about 15,000 lines of "other stuff going on", and these lines where not originally exactly like this. The variables are pulled from XML, there is data validation and try/catch blocks, all sorts of stuff. So, I started pulling the pertinent lines out, and put them in a tiny separate script, and hard coded the variables. And there, it works, I get a nice 3010 exit code and off to the races. So, I took my working code, hard coded variables and all, and pasted it back into the original script, and it breaks again.
So, I moved the code out of the function where it belongs, and just put it after I initialize everything and before I start working through the main loop. And there it works! Now, I gotta believe it's the usual "polluted pipeline", but dang if I can figure out what could cause this. My next step I guess is to just start stepping through the code, dropping this nugget in somewhere, run the test, if it works move it farther down, try again. Gack!
So, hopping someone has some insights. Either what it might be, or perhaps an improved test protocol. Or some trick to actually see the whole pipeline and somehow recognize the pollution.

FWIW, I normally work with PoSH v2, but I have tried this with v4 with the exact same results. But perhaps there is some pipeline monitoring feature in a later version that could help with the troubleshooting?

Also, my understanding is that PoSH v2 has issues with negative return codes, so they can't be trusted. But I think newer versions fixed this, correct? So the fact that I get the same code in v4 means it is meaningful to Google? Not that I have found any hint of that exit code anywhere thus far.

Crossed fingers.

EDIT: OK, a little more data. I searched on the exit code without the -, and with DuckDuckGo instead of Google, and found this.
***0x8024001E -2145124322 WU_E_SERVICE_STOP Operation did not complete because the service or system was being shut down.*** 
OK, that's some direction. And I have some code that would allow me to kill a service temporarily. But that seems a little draconian. Isn't the whole point of this, like 10th way to install updates from Microsoft, supposed to be to make automation easier? In any case, I can't find any indication there are command line flags for WUSA that would avoid the problem, but I have to believe I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved! After tracking a number of different errors trying different things, including turning off the firewall and such, it turns out the error isn't that a service won't stop, but that a service won't start. See, some of that 15K lines of code suppresses Windows Update for the duration of my script, because Windows Update causes lots of Autodesk deployments to fail, which is the whole point of my code. Well, of course WUSA needs that service. So, it looks like, rather than suppressing Windows Update for the duration of script execution, I need to be less heavy handed and only suppress for the duration of a deployment task. that will take a few hours to implement and test, but is totally doable. And probably more elegant anyway. Woot!

And yeah, for once it wasn't me pooping in my pipeline unintentionally. ;)